# How to get Winston-daily-rotate-file to rotate weekly

Tags: logging, winston

I'm using winston-daily-rotate-file for a Node project. How can I make the log file rotate weekly?

Answer (score 2):

From the description of [winston-daily-rotate-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file)
we can see the option of 
`datePattern`: "A string representing the [moment.js date format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to be used for rotating. The meta characters used in this string will dictate the frequency of the file rotation. For example, if your datePattern is simply 'HH' you will end up with 24 log files that are picked up and appended to every day. (default: 'YYYY-MM-DD')" 
So to answer your question, a simple way to make the log file rotate weekly is to set `datePattern: 'YYYY-w'`, where `w` is the Week of the Year: 1 2 ... 52 53. 
More options for the datePattern can be found in the [moment.js date format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

A simple usage is shown below.

```
  const winston = require('winston');
  const DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

  var winston = require('winston');
  require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

  var transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: 'application-%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-w'
  });

  transport.on('rotate', function(oldFilename, newFilename) {
     logger.info({'message':'New file created!'});
  });

  var logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
      transport
    ]
  });

  logger.info('Hello World!');
```

So, the log files will be named like `application-year-week.log`
E.g. Week from 6 Jul 2020 to 12 Jul 2020 is week number 28 of 2020. That means that file `application-2020-28.log` will be created for this week, `application-2020-29.log` for the next week, etc. You can calculate what week of the year is from this [Week Number Calculator](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html)